It's time to admit that Discussions have failed; can we please turn it off?
Discussions has been a poorly received product almost from the outset, and it's still a bad product.
At the moment, there are less than 900 undeleted posts (even though it's been live for over a year), and presumably many more deleted posts (certainly there are 1,000's of deleted spam posts). It is impossible to validate how well these posts are received (no SEDE and no downvotes), but engagement is very low. Most mornings, I drop in and end up flagging 70%+ of the posts that I can see as Spam, and another 10%-20% as Not suitable for Discussions (almost all of these are from 1 rep users posting incredibly low quality posts, that should have asked, been sent to the SG and had their post improved or never released).
This has been how the "feature" has worked since the outset; it is not a new thing.
I get that Stack Overflow tried, but it's clear the feature is dead; no improvements to curators has come to try and make things better:

Still no community edits
Still no API

Charcoal can't help with the frequent spam that go to the site and stays there for sometimes hours


Still no flag history
Still no downvotes (yes, it's needed).
Doesn't appear in SEDE.
I think it doesn't appear in the data dump (someone please correct me if I'm wrong).

The engagement level is terrible. On the front page, as I look at this right now, the 15 posts fit into the categories:

9 spam
2 not suitable for discussions
4 Discussions

2 barely more than a sentence


All score of 0

This is how it looks every day.
If the product actually had had some attention over the last few months, it might actually be an MVP (minimal viable product), it is not; it's not viable.
If Stack Overflow want to finish the product, and try it again in the future, then sure, but the area is just attracting bad content that is impossible to curate effectively, and which goes completely against what the community and company should expect of the site: high quality content.

Frankly, I never actually see discussions. As far as I can see, they take very minimal space in the UI anyway. Does not seem like it's causing a problem. I'd prefer they got rid of collectives, they are a bit more "in your face", and actively distracting.

Quite related to @yivi's comment: how are people intended to discover Discussions?  Is it advertised anywhere besides the left menu?

Honestly, the fact that so many 1 rep users do find, and then go and ask a (normally very low quality) question really confuses me, @RyanM . I have often wondered "What did you do to end up here?"

@RyanM as per the introduction on the top if accessed from the left menu, there's Discussions tab inside each Collective: "Threaded, public conversations on technical topics. Available for any tag on Stack Overflow and [these 8] collectives." Now, are there more discussions from collectives' tags compared to other tags? I don't know...

Ahh, @AndrewT.,  we could use as SEDE to find that, o.... oh...

The fact you cannot perform SEDE and you cannot downvote suggests this feature was always setup to fail. We as users cannot improve the content or even moderate it, its inability to use SEDE, means no analysis of the content can be done. Collectives are another thing we should take out back behind the barn….

@RyanM at one point they mentioned something about showing a button for creating a discussion along with the ask question button to new users. I don't know whether that was done or what the results were of it.

IMO it's not that discussions should be gone, it's that there should be a plan for discussions with respect to moderation, encouraging high-quality content, discriminating between high-quality and high-engagement content, discoverability, etc., with reasonable timelines (so not let it stew for a year then we'll see). The idea that we should have a less restrictive environment to discuss is almost as old as SO itself (the old programmers.se), and this need is still unfulfilled since discussions is broken.

I've tried that avenue too, @ErikA . That nothing (of consequence) has materialised or changed since the spam of '24, when [so] described the product as an "MVP" (which as a community I think many/all agree it's not) just shows that there are no plans for improvement. I've asked for stats and reiterated the request for a minimum rep requirement, and we're still in the same position we were before; mostly spam and low quality content.

@ThomA I don't disagree that there's a major problem. I just see it as the company failing to properly execute on discussions, not an inherent failure of the concept. If the company makes a plan to take this beyond it's current "MVP" status (which is more like pre-alpha), it may yet have potential. Though it may be worth shutting down until an adequate plan has been made and the resources to be able to execute on that plan have been committed.

It seems to function as an implementation of the "Crap Overflow" idea from many years ago. You could choose to think of it as a harmless place to dissipate the "crap" energy that might otherwise be directed at the main site. Personally, I think it was born useless and then got worse. We certainly don't need a discussions site, at least not associated with Stack Overflow.

Sites in public beta have this 1 requirement where they are shut down if they become mostly/exclusively bad content. I think this should apply to new features as well. Please turn it off.

I feel like the main issue, other than receiving hardly any love from the company after introduction, is the total failure to integrate it into the site... both in a technical sense and a more abstract one. It's sectioned off in its own corner and hard to find (much like chat, frankly), to the point that you have to go out of your way to engage with it at all. It's also socially unintegrated; they gave zero incentive (and I don't mean rep) for existing site members to engage with it in any capacity... I think it'd be closer to true MVP if they made it feel more tightly tied to the site.

Aside from the problems you mentioned, it's effectively unmoderated, because moderators simply don't see flagged posts on Discussions until they go to the Discussions page. And, to my knowledge, none of us ever do that. There's no reason we would want to, for the reasons you noted. This means that the classic "broken windows" problem is even bigger. There's no guidance given; there's no good examples. It's terrible. There's no better way to put it. If this kind of content was something we wanted and could work on SO, we should just allow it in the Q&A format, not give it a new separate place.

Let's just get rid of collectives altogether.

Based on the database schema, it is included in the data dump: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede/2678#2678

@M-- It indeed is listed in the schema, but only posts of the first 8 types actually come up in SEDE.

@zcoop98 talking about Data Dump not SEDE.

Had never been to discussions before. Opened it for the first time and this was the first post: https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/79033544/i-want-to-join-occult-for-money-ritual-2349120399438
Hard to argue with OPs point after that...

Similar to others, I've been a SO contributor for over ten years and read this title and thought to myself,' what in the hell are discussions?' So I went and found the link and saw the first two posts: Temu Coupon Code ╰┈➤ [acq523678]: >>|||$250 Off ||| and something in Russian. Yeah, I won't be clicking that link again.

@CodyGray A quibble: it's not unmoderated; there are dedicated moderators for that section of the site (and some of the diamond mods help out as well).  The larger issue with spam is that there was no attempt made to make it work with the community spam-protection systems like Smoke Detector, so very obvious spam stays up a lot longer than it would on the main site.

It's not as if the spam is hidden and requires SD to locate it, @Ryan. Anyone who intends to moderate Discussions looking at the page would be sufficient to clean it up. Yet, every time I look at it, it's got tons of spam posts, many that are hours old. Thus, I conclude that it is effectively unmoderated. The "larger issue" that you note may well be true, and will certainly cause problems for scaling in the future, but we're nowhere near there yet, and that isn't the central reason that the entire page looks like a broken window. Before Charcoal, spam Qs didn't live this long on SO.

So other than the data dump, it would actually be very easy to just completely ignore it. Because as others have said, I have to actively remember it exists to even be aware of it. If it is a pain to curate it... don't curate it. It'll disappear on its own eventually.

"It'll disappear on its own eventually." I'm not sure it will though, @Gimby . If it were, then Discussions probably should have already disappeared by now.

Just let it rot. Nothing of value was lost.

@ThomA The company never does anything fast, first they need to see graphs that it hurts the bottom line.

Well, they are (wanting to) introducing new graphs, @Gimby . ;) Shame they aren't demonstrating "Discussions number not go up".

I just don't see discussions as it is currently built as a great fit for a Q&A site. If SO wasn't a Q&A site and instead was more of a blog it would serve as being a mediocre replacement for a forum-like system, but SO IS a Q&A site and thus we already have a place for creating useful content... Q&A.
The community would be better served by giving chat the improvements it deserves (API? Tools to support chat bots? better flagging system?) and putting a link to it in the menu.

But Q&A won't accept the questions that Discussions is generating, and chat can't really handle single-topic discussions like that either. For a good example of a Discussion, consider "Most Useful New PHP Features for version 8?" There are also a lot of Discussions on soft topics. (Discussions and chat, of course, both have their own unresolved problems.)

Why can't chat handle such discussions? i know it could back when JS chat for example was populated before the welcoming killed it. Sure, you couldn't easily refer back to past discussions or have a discussion over the course of weeks without spinning off a separate room, but back when it wasn't dead you could certainly have such discussions. (and it's certainly still possible to spin off new rooms for longer time period discussion topics.)

You're correct that Q&A doesn't currently accept many of the questions being asked in discussions, though i'd argue that's largely because they aren't really questions, they are search terms looking for a blog article result.

"you couldn't easily refer back to past discussions or have a discussion over the course of weeks without spinning off a separate room". This is exactly what I mean. Though many Discussions are broad, they're not as broad as "Anything JavaScript" so you can refer back to previous Discussions, no matter how old (well, in theory, but search ain't great). Blogs meanwhile are a completely different niche, with the biggest difference being that they're non-interactive and therefore usually represent only one voice.

One voice that is well presented is better than a dozen ai generated or one line "X is best!" responses from randoms. that said, even in that case, Q&A is a better framework for that kind of question than discussions is... even it being currently off topic.

@Laurel SO doesn't necessarily need to handle every single programming-something topic that someone might want to discuss at any given time. That's in fact the reason why there are so many spawn-off SE sites like Software Engineering, Code Review, Software Recommendations etc etc.
